# Where to put Laravel validation that is not related to column

Tags: laravel, validation, coding-style, refactoring, laravel-validation

For example, I have an HTTP request that handles some entity creation (let it be Role)
And validation looks like this:

```
class CreateRole extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'permissions' => ['required', 'array'],
...
```

And I have some restrictions that are not related to either name or permission column.
For example the maximum amount of roles that can be created.

Such custom validation can be placed to the `name` property, but it looks wrong.

*PS: I know about custom validators. Question about where to place it...*

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I will create a custom validation rule for it anyway, the question what column it will be linked to or where to place this custom validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after hook` in the form request `CreateRole.php`

```php
class CreateRole extends FormRequest
{    
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'permissions' => ['required', 'array'],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            if (Role::count() > 10) {
                $validator->errors()->add('limit', 'Max number of Roles reached!');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, I can specify an error key that is not related to field key

Answer (score -1):

You have to create custom validation class as shown in this [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-rule-objects) and place into you validatior class like below.

```
 'name' => ['required', 'string', new CustomValidationClass],
```

Comment: this answer is not relevant, please take a look at current answer to understand what was the question